# I dont know what the problem im facing is, index.js:1 The above error occurred in one of your React components: my console is showing this problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geojson, preventdefault, react-leaflet

### My page is not loading

### Console Errors

1. index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop
2. Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, properties, geometry}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
3. The above error occurred in one of your React components:

**What I personally think is that prevent default function is not actually running you can find it inside the input tag**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { MapContainer,TileLayer,GeoJSON  } from 'react-leaflet';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import Cities from './cities.json';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import './CountryMap.css'




const CountryMap = () => {

const[searchtext,setsearch] = useState('');



  const demarcatedCountry = () =>{
    return(Cities.features.map((City)=>{
      return(
        <GeoJSON
        data={City}
        >
        </GeoJSON>
      );
     
    }));
  }

  const searchCity = () => {
    return(Cities.features.filter((city)=>{
      if (searchtext===""){
        return city
      }
      else if(searchtext===city.properties.NAME_3){
        return(
          city
        );
      }
      return(
        <GeoJSON
        data={city}
        style={{color:"red",
        fillColor:"pink"

      }}
        >

        </GeoJSON>
        )
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <form action="" className='form'>
          <input
          value={searchtext} 
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Search city" 
          className="searchBar"  
          onChange={e =>{setsearch(e.target.value) 
           e.preventDefault()}}/>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} className="searchIcon" />
        </form>

        <MapContainer
        center={[30.964750, 70.939934]}
        zoom={5}
        style={{width:"100%", 
          height:"100vh"}}
       
        
        >
        <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
       
        />
        {demarcatedCountry()}
        {searchCity()}
        

        </MapContainer>

      
    </div>
  );
};

export default CountryMap;
```

Comment: when i removed the return of searchCity function i can load my page now but the problem is that i cannot render two GeoJSON layers on a single map

Comment: You're not using `.filter()` correctly, you can see [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to see how to use it. Also, when mapping to JSX elements, you should add a `key` prop. See [react's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) on how to use the key prop